# What happens to the memory of my aborted object?

Tags: memory-management, c++-cli

I have a class "Texture", that in its constructor checks for illegal values entered by the user. If the user enters an illegal value, the constructor throws one of two exceptions, and execution breaks out of the constructor and into the relevant catch block. See the code below:

```
SSViewer::SSViewer(System::Windows::Forms::Form ^ parentForm, GLsizei iWidth, GLsizei iHeight) : COpenGL(parentForm,iWidth,iHeight)
{
    printf("\nSuper inherited COGL const func GO");
    cbColour = gcnew array<GLfloat>(4); 
    cbColour[0] = 0.7f;
    cbColour[1] = 0.2f;
    cbColour[2] = 0.6f;
    cbColour[3] = 0.4f;
    //Test Texture
    try
    {
        //Test Texture
        Texture* myTex = new Texture("C4 Games 2.png");
    }
    catch(Texture::nonPOTException& e)
    {
        System::String^ err = gcnew System::String(e.what());
        MessageBox::Show(err, "Sprite Sheet Error", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Stop);
    }
    catch(Texture::InvalidSizeException& e)
    {
        System::String^ err = gcnew System::String(e.what());
        MessageBox::Show(err, "Sprite Sheet Error", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Stop);
    }
}
```

The line:

```
Texture* myTex = new Texture("C4 Games 2.png");
```

is the line that will throw the exception. However if it does throw, the control is returned to the catch block before construction of myTex is complete. Obviously I do not want this incomplete, illegally initialised instance of Texture* to exist.

What I wish to know is in the event that construction aborted by the throw, is the memory used for the incomplete instance still in use. Do I need to call `delete` on myTex in the catch-blocks to free up the memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case standard C++ behavior applies: If the constructor invoked by `new` throws an exception, the memory is deleted.

More precisely, the `operator delete` with the same prototype as the invoked `new` will be called to free the memory.

Comment: Thank you very much. **Exactly** what I wanted to know. So I've no need/responsibility to call delete myself in the case of a thrown exception, as that is done for me by c++.

Comment: As long as your constructor itself does not leak memory when it throws, you're fine.